# Scala Advanced Type Usage

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

### The Background

I'm working on an event library in Scala. [In my library](https://github.com/goldmar/CEScala/) you can define events like this:

```
val e1 = new ImperativeEvent[Int]
```

You can trigger them like this:

```
e1(42)
```

You can create reactions like this:

```
val r1 = (i: Int) => println(i)
```

And attach them to the event like this:

```
e1 += r1
```

There is also some other stuff (like event transformations, compositions etc). I use the [Esper CEP engine](http://esper.codehaus.org/) as the backend of my library. Esper uses an SQL-like language called EPL for most operations.

### The Problem

I'm trying to implement some more advanced concepts like event joins. So now you can define events with multiple properties like this (using tuple types):

```
val e2 = new ImperativeEvent[(Int, String)]
```

And then join them like this:

```
val e3 = e1 join e2 windowLength (30) on "E1.P1 = E2.P1"
```

which performs a join of e1 and e2 on the last 30 occurrances of both on the condition that their respective first properties are equal.

This is alright but I'd like to get rid of the strings in my implementation to make the event expressions type checkable. I'd like to change the join expression to something like this:

```
val e3 = e1 join e2 windowLength (30) on e1._1 === e2._1
```

similar to the way it is done in eg. [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/). The problem with this is, I can't access the types of the elements of the tuple type...

### The Question

How can I access the tuple types statically? Right now I've only managed to access them at run-time through reflection which does not help me. I'm pretty sure that what I want to achieve is not possible with tuples but I'm wondering if using HLists from the shapeless library or something similar might help in achieving my goal.

Comment: Is seems you have `e1.join(e2).windowLength(30).on(e1._1 === e2._1)`.  What is `===` ?

Comment: **+=** seems an odd choice of operator for what you use it for here.  It implies that **ImperativeEvent** is purely or principally a collection of reactions.  If you have overridden **+** for adding any of the various things that you might add to an event, I guess that would be a bit more understandable but it still makes me queasy.

Comment: @pedrofurla E1 refers to the left event of the join, E2 to the right one. The `join` method replaces those with the appropriate internal event IDs. The actual join is made by Esper (http://esper.codehaus.org/), my library is mostly a wrapper around it. Esper is based on an SQL-like language called EPL, that's why it uses Strings. I'd like to add type checking to those Strings (similar to eg. Squeryl, that's where my `===` example comes from) but I'm not sure if this is possible with my current event representation (in which parameters are expressed as (tuple) types of the event).

Comment: @itsbruce The idea for the `+=` operator was borrowed from C#. [Check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) for a quick introduction into C# events.

Comment: So there´s precedent, I see, and you´re offering familiar usage to C# veterans.  Nasty precedent, though ;)  If it calls out to a method named something like `registerHandler`, that´d be what I´d use every time.

Comment: Having `ImperativeEvent` is not very convenient. It is mutable and it is difficult to work with. Much more convenient approach is to have a mutable builder that constructs immutable version of event processing system. The latter approach is implemented in SynapseGrid library.

Comment: For those interested, here is the result of my work: https://github.com/goldmar/CEScala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more details on your DSL, I'm afraid it's not clear what you mean by "access the tuple types statically". Here's a simplified version of the API that has no trouble with tuple types:

```
class Event[T] {
  def joinOn[T2, R](ev2: Event[T2])(f: (T, T2) => R) = new Event[R]
}
```

You can use this as follows:

```
val e1 = new Event[(Int, String)]
val e2 = new Event[(Int, String)]
val e3 = e1.joinOn(e2)(_._1 == _._2)
```

It should be easy to see how this could be extended to supporting your join/windowLength/on syntax.

**Update:** 
I can see that your use case is complicated by the fact that you need to translate the Scala-encoded query expression to another query language. In this case, you want the `on` method's signature to look like:

```
def on[T2, R](f: (Expr[T], Expr[T2]) => Expr[R]): Event[R]
```

Internally, each event object would create its own Expr representation and would pass this representation into the function supplied to the `on` method.

The `Expr` type could be defined like:

```
trait Expr[T] {
  protected val repr: String

  def _1[A](implicit ev: T <:< Tuple2[A,_]): Expr[A] = 
    ??? // create an Expr[A] whose string representation is (repr + ".P1")

  // abstracting over tuple arities (using Shapeless)
  import shapeless._, nat._
  @scala.annotation.implicitNotFound("A tuple with at least 3 elements is required")
  type At2 = ops.tuple.At[T, _2]

  def _3(implicit at: At2): Expr[at.Out] = 
    ??? // create an Expr[at.Out] whose string representation is (repr + ".P3")

  def ===(other: Expr[T]): Expr[Boolean] =
    ??? // create an Expr[T] whose string representation is (repr + " = " + other.repr)
}
```

This is obviously dramatically simplified but should help to get you started.

Comment: Now that I see the solution it looks really simple... thank you!

However, I've got one more question: As you can see from the example above, I actually need to create a String in the end... and it should contain the position of the element in the tuple rather than the actual element itself (eg. your example _._1 == _._2 should return a String "E1.P1 = E2.P2"). I probably need to enrich the Int and String types via implicits, but I'm not sure about getting the position of the element in the tuple...

Comment: I added some notes on how the API could compute a string representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your update looks much more complicated but it seems to be exactly what I need. I'll look into it in the next couple days and accept your answer then.

Comment: No problem. You'll probably still want to consider Shapeless in order to abstract over the tuple arities. Otherwise, you have to define 253 methods instead of just 22.

Comment: I'm still quite amazed how fast you came up with a solution to a problem that gave me days of headache ;-) with your help I got it working for events defined with `Tuple2` but now I'm wondering, how I can distinguish between `Tuple2` and eg. `Tuple3`? When I try adding `def _1[A](implicit ev: T <:< Tuple3[A,_,_])` to your code suggestion I get a compiler error: `double definition [both methods] have same type after erasure`.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, but it's another reason to look into Shapeless. Alternatively, you could define Tuple2Expr[T1,T2], Tuple3Expr[T1,T2,T3], etc., as implicit views of Expr[(T1, T2)], Expr[(T1,T2,T3)], etc., respectively. This non-Shapeless approach would require 22 classes and 253 method definitions!

Comment: Thanks again, that helped a lot! It works now. Maybe I'll look into Shapeless, but for now I'm just happy to have something that works, even though I need a lot of methods for this :-)

Comment: I've been interested in learning Shapeless lately, so I decided to look into this. It turned out to be quite simple -- see my recent edit, which defines an arity-neutral `_3` method and even gives a useful compiler error if the client code fails to supply a suitable tuple type.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I had some problems with your suggestion but after a little experimentation and exploration of shapeless' test cases I got it working and my version looks like this: `def _2(implicit at: At[T, _1]) = ValueExpr[at.Out](repr + ".P3")` Note the `at.Out` part; in your version the element type is not set correctly. A little drawback of using Shapeless is that IDE support has some issues.

Comment: Ah, I see I had gotten the type parameters mixed up and neglected the return type! Fixed for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I. There is a [SynapseGrid](https://github.com/Primetalk/SynapseGrid/) functional reactive programming library. In the sources you can find some helpful tips.

All processing in the library is type safe. You have complete access to tuples.

For instance if I had to implement join in SynapseGrid I would define a method `join` of the following signature:

```
implicit class RichContact[T] (c:Contact[T]){ // contact == event in SynapseGrid's terminology
  ...
  def join[T2](c2:Contact[T2]):Contact[(T, T2)] = {
    // construct a contact/event that do nothing more than joining two events.
  }
}

implicit class RichTupledContact[T, T2](c:Contact[(T, T2)])
  def windowLength(len:Int):Contact[(T, T2)] = { 
    // construct the next step of processing events — window 
  }
}
```

and so on. Gradually building event processing greatly simplifies system's construction.

II. If, however, you need to construct everything at once then you may return some intermediate object that has construction method:

```
implicit class RichContact[T] (c:Contact[T]){ // contact == event in SynapseGrid's terminology
  ...
  def join[T2](c2:Contact[T2]):Contact[(T, T2)] = {
    new {
      def windowLength(len:Int) = ...
    }
  }
}
```